# Converting dictionary to dataframe with key as column names and value of key as column values of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, flatten

Converting the nested dictionary to dataframe with, dictionary **keys** as **column names** and **values** corresponding to those keys as **column values** of the dataframe.

I'm new to python and have tried several approaches but failed in achieving so, please help.

```py
dict = {
    'sheet1': {
        'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        'col2': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'],
        'col3': ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o'],
        'col4': ['e', 'b', 'w', 't', 'b']
    },
    'sheet2': {
        'col1': ['r', 'w', 'y', 'g', 'r'],
        'col2': ['q', 'y', 'f', 'w'],
        'col3': ['w', 'g', 4, 2, 'd']
    }
}
```

```
output: 
col1    col2   col3   col4
a       p       l      e
b       q       m      b
c       r       n      w
d       s       o      t
e       t       nan    b
r       q       w      nan
w       y       g      nan
y       f       4      nan
g       w       2      nan
r      nan      d      nan
```

Comment: I think you need to work through some tutorials: your dict isn't formatted correctly and dumping a dict into pandas is pandas 101. 
 Try: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html

Comment: What are sheet1, col1, a etc? Are they strings or variables from somewhere else?

Comment: they are just strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating multiple dataframes from nested dictionaries, and joining them using `pd.concat`. For example:

```
>>> data = {
...     'sheet1': {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [5, 6, 7, 8]},
...     'sheet2': {'col1': [11, 12, 13, 14], 'col2': [15, 16, 17, 18]},
... }
>>> df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in data.values()], ignore_index=True)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     5
1     2     6
2     3     7
3     4     8
4    11    15
5    12    16
6    13    17
7    14    18
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create nested dataframes from the given dictionary and then concatenate them on each other.

Here's as sample dictionary,

```py
sample_dict = {
    'sheet1': {
        'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        'col2': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'],
        'col3': ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
    },
    'sheet2': {
        'col1': ['r', 'w', 'y', 'g', 'r'],
        'col2': ['q', 'y', 'f', 'w'],
        'col3': ['w', 'g', 4, 2, 'd'],
        'col4': ['e', 'b', 'w', 't', 'b']
    }
}
```

You can then make a list of dataframes for every key in the *sample_dict*,

```
df_list=[]
for key in sample_dict:
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in sample_dict[key].items()])))
```

Finally you concatenate the dataframes stored in the *df_list*,

```
final_df=pd.concat(df_list)
```